# Numpy array concat with different shape

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to build array based  on another two array using numpy, your help much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.arange(1, 5 + 1, 1)
array2 = np.arange(1, 2 + 1, 1)

print('array1 ==>', array1)
print('array2 ==>', array2)
```

Output:

```
array1 ==> [1 2 3 4 5]
array2 ==> [1 2]
output_array ==> [ 1.1  1.2  2.1  2.2  3.1  3.2  4.1  4.2]
```

Comment: `output_array = np.array([i + x/10 for i in array1 for x in array2])`

Comment: [Numpy broadcasting: `(array1[:, None] + array2 / 10).ravel()`](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/14ef0868.py)

Comment: Why is there no 5.1 and 5.2 in your example output? what is the pattern? it is unclear what you would want the output to be in case of numbers larger than 10 too. Please elaborate so we can help better. Thank you

Comment: @Psidom there's the broadcasting magic I was looking for! Nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list comprehension that will get the job done:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array2 = [1, 2]
output_array = [i + 0.1*j for i in array1 for j in array2]
print(output_array)  
# prints [1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2, 4.1, 4.2, 5.1, 5.2]
```

There may be some clever bit of broadcasting magic that will let you do this with numpy calls in an extremely performant way, but here's a very simple way:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array2 = [1, 2]
output_array = np.repeat(array1, 2) + np.tile(array2, 5)*0.1
print(output_array)  
# prints [1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2, 4.1, 4.2, 5.1, 5.2]
```

Personally I prefer the list comprehension approach, it's cleaner and probably faster

edit: From another person's comment, here's a sweet broadcasting approach:

```
output_array = (array1[:, None] + array2 / 10).ravel()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, if array2 values goes beyond 10 above steps not working. Example array2 = [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]

Comment: Looping is probably slower than broadcasting for large arrays. And cleanness is somewhat subjective. Broadcasting in my opinion is neater.

Comment: @Tech what is your expected output in case of that example?

Comment: @Tech all 3 solutions work for me when array2 has a size of 15 or 20. The second solution needs to use the size of the respective arrays, that may be where you're running into the problem. I recommend just using the 3rd approach though, which is the simplest